# Rotas em arquivos separados com VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Tem como eu criar rotas em arquivos separados no VueJS? 
Eu atualmente tenho essa estrutura de pasta

```
|- main.js
|
|- Grupos
  |- grupos.vue
|- Artigos
  |- artigos.vue
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

let router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [{
        path: '/Main',
        component: require('./mainPage.vue'),
        children: [{
                path: '/Main/Grupos',
                component: require('./grupos.vue')
            },
            {
                path: '/Main/Artigos',
                component: require('./artigos.vue')
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        component: require('./notFound.vue')
    }
    ]
})

const app = new Vue({router}).$mount('#container')
```

Eu queria saber se dá para minhas serem assim:

```
|- main.js
|
|- Grupos
  |- grupos.vue
  |- grupoRoutes.js
|- Artigos
  |- artigos.vue
  |- artigosRoutes.js
```

Eu sei que dá para fazer isso com **routes.add**, mas aí eu tenho que importar lá no meu **Main.JS**. Eu queria que fosse tudo independente. Sem ter que importar no **Main.js**.

Tem como eu fazer isso? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `require.context` do webpack [veja a documentação aqui](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/).

basicamente o seu `maimRutes.js` vai junta todos as esxportações default do seus arquivos `.+\.route.js`.

basicamente isso:

```js
const routes = require.context('src/', true, /\.routes\.js$/)
```